# call mixpanel using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, mixpanel

I need to use mixpanel Data Export API using jQuery.
According to this: [How can I use mixpanel API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140336/how-can-i-use-mixpanel-api) and according to mixpanel: https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/data-export-api#libs-js, I can use this:

```
$.getJSON('http://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/engage/?callback=?', {
        api_key: apiKey,
        expire: expire,
        sig: sig
    },
    function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
);
```

But as a result I get an error as result:

```
"unknown param: callback
for params: {'callback': 'jQuery18208090281161325954_1358248117308', 'project_id': 160130}"
```

I know that the url and my data is correct since when I open browser in `http://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/engage/?api_key=...&expire=...&sig=...` I get correct data.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

The `callback` parameter works for other endpoints like `.../events/top` and `.../funnels/list`, but this error is returned for this particular `engage` endpoint.

You will have to raise this as an issue with Mixpanel, that this endpoint does not support JSONP callbacks.

Somewhat confusingly, you can *post* data using a different `engage` endpoint, by following the instructions on this page: 
https://mixpanel.com/docs/people-analytics/people-http-specification-insert-data

Here is an example that works with this endpoint:

```
var mixpanel_token = "<insert token for your mixpanel project here>";
var myData = { "$set": {         
                  "$first_name": "John", 
                  "$last_name": "Smith" },
                "$token": mixpanel_token, 
                "$distinct_id": "99999", 
                "$ip": "0" };

var dataEncodedToBase64 = window.btoa(JSON.stringify(myData));

var path = 'http://api.mixpanel.com/engage?callback=?';

$.getJSON(path, { 'data': dataEncodedToBase64, 'verbose': 1 }, function(json) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(json);
});
```

Just note that your code should work for the other endpoints in the link you provided in your question, just not for `engage`.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me! Is there any way to update user properties without change the Last Seen property? (I need to sync user's data from my db). Any idea?